# SCSS selection with "&". Advanced trick

Tags: css, sass

I have a button class `.btn` and want to select only when it is with a link. What to add to `a` so I will get `a.btn` using SCSS and my code bellow?

SCSS:

```
.btn {
   background: red;

   a {
     background: blue;
   }
}
```

I want to get this in css:

```
.btn {
  background: red;
}

a.btn {
  background: blue;
}
```

Logical will be to do this `a&`. But it gives an error. `a &` and `& a` is giving a different result.

---

I know that this can be done with `@at-root a#{&}` but it is too ugly =) Is there a pretty way?

```
.btn {
   background: red;

   @at-root a#{&} {
     background: blue;
   }
}
```

Comment: what is the output of `a &`?... AFAIK it should work

Comment: @Pipe `a .btn {}`

Comment: hhhmmm... i understand.

Comment: then `@at-root a#{&}` is your friend

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
a {
    &.btn {
        background: blue;
    }
}

.btn {
    background: red;
}
```

You can't write that in a single block. In case if that's what you are trying to do.

Comment: Yes you can with @at-root a#{&}. But it is too ugly =)

Answer (score 0):

Since `.btn&` is not a valid scss, it seems that `@at-root a#{&}` is your only option.

Comment: But it is the same as just writing it outside the block. It will be even much clearer =)